# css responsive dropdown menu - determine edge of screen ( div )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have responsive dropdown menu.

[image: drop-down]

I want to fix the overflow of submenus. I want to determine screen edge and if submenu is overfloating edge, then change its align to other side.

### Problem:

When I hover on submenu, they hit edge and overflow.

[image: overflow]

### Question:

How to determine edge of screen (div) and change align of submenu to other side ?
(prevent submenus to overflow screen)

### JSFIDDLE:

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/BrPeY/)

### CSS:

```
.edge {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

### JS:

```
 $(".menu li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

    var elm = $('ul:first', this);
    var off = elm .offset();
    var l = off.left;
    var w = elm.width();
    var docH = $(".container").height();
    var docW = $(".container").width();

    var isEntirelyVisible = (l+ w <= docW);

    if ( ! isEntirelyVisible ) {
        $(this).addClass('edge');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('edge');
    }
});
```

Comment: i think that in the responsive versión you should convert it to accordion... very complex to keep the navigation style.. just like in your fiddle looks great

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet in mobile view ( less than < 480px ) it is working as accordion, but in desktop view it is dropdown

Comment: I would also say that that many nested menus is not very use friendly

Comment: @ExplosionPills I agree, that is why I use 4-level submenu as last resort.